# How to change the android package name from two parts to three parts

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm new to android development. And recently I bought an app template and it has two package name. company.appname. I want to change it to com.company.appname.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**1. You can the package name from the `app:module gradle`**

[image]

**2. and also you can rename the module from the project structure**

[image]

**3. for more info please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29092698/12830957) thanks to `@Sheharyar`**